Mellin Transform of $1/(1 - x)$
What is the Mellin transform of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ ?
According to the book "Tables of Mellin Transforms" by F. Oberhettinger, page 14 (entry 2.12):
For $s$ complex such that $0 < \Re(s) < 1$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{a-x} = \pi a^{s-1} \cot(\pi s)$$
Without specifying a word about $a$. Please help me understand how to calculate such integral, specifically for the case where $a = 1$.
My questions are:

Why does the Mellin transform of $(a - x)^{-1}$ result in $\pi a^{s-1} \cot(\pi s)$?
What is the justification for the domain $0 < \Re(s) < 1$?
For which values of $a$ is this transform valid, and how does the principal value come into play?


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803422/integral-p-int-0-infty-fracx-lambda-11-x-dx?noredirect=1

"Without specifying a word about $a$." In the last paragraph of the Preface, the author writes: "Latin letters (unless otherwise stated) denote real positive numbers (...)".

You're right!!! so indeed $0<a$ real number.
